# Integration of an exponential: $\int \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I've been trying to compute the following form, however, I'm not getting any results. Any suggestions?

$$\int \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \,dx$$

Comment: This is not something that can be closed-form integrated, not even when $a=0$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). To help you get started, I have retyped the text from your picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As  Parcly Taxel commented, there is no hope for a closed form, except for $a=0$.

In this last case, assuming $\sqrt {x^2}=x$, this would reduce to 
$$\int \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx=\text{Ei}(-x)$$ where appears  the exponential integral function.

For your problem, we could write
$$\frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}=\frac 1x \left(1+\frac {a^2}{x^2} \right)^{-\frac 12}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}\frac{a^{2 n}} { x^{2 n+1}}$$ and face the problem of computing 
$$I_n=\int \frac{e^{-x}}{ x^{2 n+1}}\,dx=-\Gamma (-2 n,x)$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function.